# Is there a free text diff GUI tool that allows to show only differences?

Tags: windows, diff

Beyond Compare allows to show only differences, or only differences with context. I tried Meld, KDiff, and WinMerge, but none of them seem to have this feature, which is really handy when files get too large.

It must run on Windows, should be free, as otherwise I can just buy Beyond Compare is it is < $50.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not want you want, but Linux tools are often very versatile and powerful:

The commandline tool [**diff**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) will output only differences by default. You can download it for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm). Just run it from cmd.exe like this:`diff.exe file1 file2 > output.txt`, if you want to view the output in your Windows editor of choice. That may be not very comfortable, but you could just turn that into a batch file.

If you are already familiar with Linux you could even use the [Linux Bash for Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) and just pipe the output directly to your Linux editor of choice:

```
diff file1 file2 | gvim /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Aplogies for posting an answer when I feel this should only be a comment - but that's the only way to get a screenshot posted.

Like you, I preer Beyoned Compare, showing only differences.  WinMerge, my goto diff tool when gratis is a requiement does not offer this features, ***but*** it does have an overview pane on the left, like this

[image]

and you can click on those yellow bars to jump to the next difference. `Alt + down arrow` also jumps to the next difference.

I was about to suggest that you request this as new feature - but [someone beat us to it](http://forums.winmerge.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1205).

Comment: It might be quite simple to implement a plugin or filter for Winmerge that achieves this.

Comment: And the WinMerge source code is [available for download](http://winmerge.org/downloads/source-code.php)