# Find almost-identical folders for windows

Tags: duplicate-files

Looking for a software that will scan a folder (and all its sub-folders tree) and will output Folders that have a lot of files in common.

Comment: Can you define "have a lot of files in common"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*Fast Duplicate File Finder*](https://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm) to accomplish this if you are looking for duplicate files or duplicate files with different names in multiple directories or the same directory.  Files that are similar or a duplicate with a different name will be grouped together with the folders the files are in.

From Widipedia, "Fast Duplicate File Finder is a Windows tool developed by MindGems Inc, available as a freeware version and a full commercial version. It is intended to scan a user's computer for duplicate files, display a list of such files and let the user delete unneeded copies with the purpose of freeing up hard drive space."

"

Comment: A link to the application would improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you require is not clear in your question. However, a program for the Windows OS called [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/) will display small icons on the folder and file views to indicate differences within folders and files. Useful if you want a visual overview of differences. Plus see the answers in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3294) and [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/) which cover the tools [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/), [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), and [krusader](https://krusader.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a basic script (maybe in PowerShell) that recursively interates into two folders retrieving, for example, filenames, sizes, dates and other attributes. Save such info into a couple of hash tables and diff them with some criteria. Et voilà.

Comment: It'll take the script a very very long time to do so - I need it to search thousands of folders. It has to be quit sophisticated